# How do I get vimeo videos to play properly?

Tags: video, firefox, google-chrome

YouTube videos play fine in Firefox and Chrome. However, Vimeo videos are always choppy. What can I do to get them to play normally?

I'm running a Tecra A4 with a VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc M24 1P [Radeon Mobility X600]

Screenshot per comment request
[image]

Comment: How much is your CPU used (and how many cores do you have) while you're watching the video?

Comment: How do I find that out?

Comment: Close voters see http://askubuntu.com/a/13690/169736

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've lost possession of the laptop, so I'm going to "close" this question with an answer that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for doing this, it helps keep the site clean and tidy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/adobe 
echo "OverrideGPUValidation=true" > ~/mms.cfg 
sudo mv ~/mms.cfg /etc/adobe/
```

It will force Flash Player to bypass its GPU validity checks.

Make sure you have the latest driver for your graphics card.

Source: http://blogs.adobe.com/penguinswf/2008/08/secrets_of_the_mmscfg_file_1.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that code, it didn't change things for me.

Comment: @Davious Do you have the latest driver for your video card?

Comment: Yep. It's an ATI card on a Tecra A4

Comment: @Davious Please add your hardware information to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Get [FlashVideoReplacer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/161869/), an extension for Firefox that I develop, which allows you to watch YouTube, Vimeo and Blip.tv with a different plugin like gecko mediaplayer, gxine, kaffeine, mozplugger, totem or xine. CPU usage will drop considerably and you will be able to watch fullscreen HD.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added the plug-in and I still see choppy vimeo videos.

Comment: Are they being loaded with a different plugin or still with flash? Please post a screenshot.

Comment: @Davious I can't see which plugin you are using from the screenshot.

Comment: Hmm.. let's see. I just realized that I needed to go to Ubuntu Software Center and install Gnome MPlayer with the gecko mediaplayer option.  I installed that. Still choppy video. But I sense I'm making progress.

Comment: I'm not sure what to add to the screenshot to make it more helpful. I invite suggestions.

Comment: @Davious When you open a video at Vimeo, can you actually see the gecko-mediaplayer controls? They are very different from the vimeo player and should look like this: http://lh4.ggpht.com/_EPRFmO0pKhs/S_QyVM-XaeI/AAAAAAAAAPU/smerRb4XWOM/s800/flvideoreplacer_vimeo_gecko.png

Comment: I don't see the gecko mediaplayer controls. I see the "regular" video controls, this is despite seeing Gecko Media Player listed as the player for most of my mimetypes in Firefox's Manage Content Plug-in Dialog.

Comment: @Davious Can you see them on YouTube videos?

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo offers a HTML5 version of their player as alternative to Flash. It works much smoother for me.

Comment: Rather than being [a half-answer in a comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments), this answer should instead ideally be modified to explain how to use the HTML5 version of the player, or at least to contain a link to information about it.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I would add my 25cents because I came here looking for help for a similar issue a few minutes ago. Until 30seconds ago, all Vimeo gave me was a still image of the video but no play button. YouTube was fine, and I could watch Vimeo vids via Chrome. The short answer is, I decided to disable *Flashblock* and that did it. So while that may not be your answer, it might be helpful to the next guy (like me) who bumps into this thread.